# Missions counter stuck

Tags: rocksmith-2014

When I visit the Rocksmith 60 day challenge website, the missions completed count always remains the same since a few weeks... Other stats such as the days completed, total song attempts etc. are not affected. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

The [60-day-challenge](http://rocksmith.ubi.com/rocksmith/en-US/players/global.aspx) site has received a lot of attention at the [Ubisoft forums](http://forums.ubi.com/forumdisplay.php/534-Rocksmith-2014-60-Day-Challenge). Mostly negative.

The general consensus in the forums is that it's not working correctly. Even if it is working correctly, there are a few inescapable problems:

- Lack of transparency: A lack of in game counters means you cannot draw a link between what you do in game and what the site reports.
- Lack of clarity: Contradictory information between different sources means people have to resort to experimentation to figure out what the actual rules are.
- Lack of consistency: Some things one would expect to be tracked apparently aren't - which is very counter-intuitive.
- Poor reliability: There's a lot of anecdotal evidence that (in spite of Ubisoft's claims otherwise), sometimes things just don't work correctly. And unfortunately, due to the previously mentioned problems, it's impossible to prove either way.

As for the **mission counter** on the site, I do have my suspicions. (Disclaimer: I have not seen any official information to corroborate my theory, but we're back to the problems mentioned earlier.)

- I usually complete a few missions every day. But the site often reports a smaller increase of missions completed than what I actually did during the session. It's also remained stuck for a few days until I complete a different kind of mission.
- So I suspect all missions fall into one of two categories: "set missions" and "bonus missions". If you complete the same mission multiple times (e.g. Play 1 new song), the first time might count as a set mission, the rest as bonus.
- The achievements (Mission 214 and Hitting .500) seem to track both types of mission, whereas the site seems to track only "set missions". The reason I say this is that I have the Mission 214 achievement, but according to the site, I've only completed 120 missions.
- The other thing I've noticed is that I sometimes gain access to new unlockable items when succeeding at something - in spite of that success not being listed as a "current mission". This suggests the "success" might have been one of the "set missions". (Again, the lack of transparency makes this difficult to verify.)

#### Summary

There is certainly enough reason to believe the 60-day challenge counters (missions completed, days practice, hours played, ...) are going to be less that what you've *actually* done. But don't let that discourage you... you've probably done a little more than what the counters show. But I doubt they're over-counting; so whatever it shows is what you've achieved at a minimum - congratulations!

... and remember to keep having fun! :)